# Resolving a service in autofac without registering service type

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

Is it possible to resolve a service in autofac without registering it with the container?

So far I have come up with something like this:

```
    public object ResolveUnknownService(IContainer container, Type serviceType)
    {
        ILifetimeScope lifetimeScope = container.BeginLifetimeScope(b => b.RegisterType(serviceType).ExternallyOwned());
        try
        {
            return lifetimeScope.Resolve(serviceType);
        }
        finally
        {
            lifetimeScope.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

It works, but I am a bit worried about performance. I also don't want to use AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource beacuse I want to be specific about which services I want (or don't want) to resolve this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, disposing the temporary lifetime scope will dispose the object being returned as well as any of its dependencies; components only live as long as the lifetime scope that they were resolved from.

Are there any known criteria that identifies these types? There is an overload of the `AnyConcrete...` class's constructor that can specify a filter on what it will resolve. If there are such criteria though then `RegisterAssemblyTypes()` is almost always a better option.

(Unless you're integrating with a legacy/third-party framework then this pattern is probably not the best way to use Autofac, as it leads down the Service Locator path. YMMV of course.)

Comment: In my example, I use ExternallyOwned at the end of registration, so I think the component should live after the temporary lifetime scope was disposed.

Comment: The main scenario is for plugin system in our app. Plugins can have their dependencies injected through constructor and some dependencies are only known at resolve time. We have wrapped Autofac with typed parameters in our object/plugin factory. The API usage looks something like this: objectFactory.New(typeof(MyPlugin)).WithParameter(typeof(MyDependency), myDependencyValue).Build(). This creates new instance of MyPlugin. Type MyDependency may or may not be in the constructor and there can also be other dependencies which have already been registered with Autofac.

Comment: If the component has dependencies that are disposable, these will still be disposed regardless whether or not `ExternallyOwned()` is used. Resolving and keeping alive an `Owned<T>` may be a better option for you. You might also find some interest in the way that MEF (and Autofac) can combine `IEnumerable<T>` with `Lazy<T,M>` to deal with plug-in selection scenarios - http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata